# PHPExcel handling cell value special ñ

Tags: php, phpexcel

good day

i have a problem when uploading a excel data that have a ñ it becomes an different symbols. i want to know what should i add to  echo or upload it to database that it never change the "ñ" in to symbol.

this is my code to collect the cell value

```
    $cellValue = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
```

can anyone to help what should i add in my code to echo or save it to the database in ñ format

THANKS IN ADVANCE GUYS !

Comment: is the charset of the project UTF-8?

Comment: PHPExcel ensures that all cell values are converted to UTF-8. Ensure that you're displaying $cellValue on a UTF-8 page, or handled as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response guys

this code help me to save ñ to database

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

$cellValue = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();

Try this:
$cellValue1 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
$cellValue=utf8_decode($cellValue1);

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little bit?  Also Read